# How to stop a function from executing more than x times per day?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets Script, how do I stop a function from executing more than x e.g. 5 times a day?

For instance, I have a trigger that executes a function every 20 minutes that sends an email based on a condition in the function, however I only want it to send this email a maximum of 5 times a day. How would I do this?

Comment: Keep count in the propertiesService.

Comment: [See this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)  Believe you're going to need to use `getDocumentProperties()`.  It'd be easy if you use date as the key, albeit depending on how you're doing this a clever user could change it.  You could work around it with [a time server](https://j11y.io/snippets/getting-the-real-time-in-javascript/).

Answer (score 2):

As other users recommended, you can store a value in the [Project Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setpropertykey,-value), and use it to count how many times the script has been executed. I recommend you to use a condition to compare the new property with `5`.

> Remind to convert the property returned result type to Integer, as it is an
>   String by default, otherwise you won't be able to add 1 in each
>   execution.

As an example we can use the [setProperty](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to modify the already saved value, for example:

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var newValue = +userProperties.getProperty('Execution_times') + 1;

userProperties.setProperty('Execution_times', newValue); // Updates stored value.
```